# How to get the expiration time of the ssl certification of a kubernetes cluster with kubernetes-python-client?

Tags: kubernetes

I have four kubernetes clusters, and I want to check the expiration time of them with kubernetes-python-client.

I am following this page: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python

Is there anyone know how to get it?

Comment: Expiration of what exact certificate? In kubernetes itself it's a lot of them.

Comment: expiration of certificates which get used into ingress ?

Comment: those SSL/TLS get stored into Kubenetes secret and you get the secret using the python client and run this command to check the date of exploration : https://learn.akamai.com/en-us/webhelp/enterprise-application-access/enterprise-application-access/GUID-9D88336D-2733-4325-913C-916403E03D48.html

Comment: @zerkms I am sorry for not being clear, if for an exact certificate it should be apiserver.

Comment: @HarshManvar Thanks, but I do not want to get it by command line...

Answer (score 1):

The apiserver certificate is generally handled out of band, either by your Kubernetes installer tool (kubeadm, rancher, talos, etc) or off-cluster in a load balancer layer. As such the K8s API won't help you with this.

That said, you can get the certificate of any HTTPS server in Python using `ssl.get_server_certificate()` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.get_server_certificate) along with other functions in the `ssl` module to parse the cert data and then look at the Not After timestamp.